# 2023 – Is there any way to distinguish if user is using Brave or Safari on mobile or detect correctly Brave on mobile?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, safari, brave

Actually, I am looking for a solution to distinguish Brave and Safari on mobile. For now, after my code implementation, iPhone treats Brave as Safari.
Maybe there is any way to determine if the user is using Brave?

After removing Brave from the userAgent, none of the available solutions are working.

My actual code:

```
import * as Bowser from "bowser";

export class AppModal implements OnInit {
  isModalVisible = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    const browser = Bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent).getBrowser().name.toLowerCase();
    const isSafari = browser === 'safari';

    // detect Brave browser

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()

    request.open('GET', 'https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=useragent&format=json', true)

    request.onload = function () {
      const data = JSON.parse(this.response)
      const isBrave = data['Answer'].includes('Brave');
      alert(data['Answer']);
      console.log(data['Answer']);
    }

    request.send();
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.isModalVisible = false;
  }
}
```

The first "Bowser" package is correctly recognizing all of the browsers except Brave (Safari === Brave for mobile), XMLHttpRequest() is recognizing Brave but only for the browser, on mobile devices, it is defined as Safari.

I need one of those two – distinguish Safari vs Brave on mobile or detect Brave on mobile correctly using JavaScript or Angular.

Does anyone have any idea how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, all web browsers (including brave) and web views are using the webkit web view. There would be no way to tell the difference without the browser changing their user agent.